# How to select first two children of an element without :nth pseudo-classes?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am currently preparing myself for a regional championship in web development for high-school students. Preparation tasks are one the championships website to solve. I have the following HTML code:

```html
<h2>Task 5</h2>
<article id="task-5">
    <div class="marble"></div>
    <div class="marble"></div>
    <section>
        <div class="marble" data-target></div>
        <div class="marble" data-target></div>
        <section>
            <div class="marble"></div>
            <div class="marble"></div>
        </section>
    </section>
</article>
```

My goal is to select the divs with the `marble` class marked with `data-target`, but under following requirements:

- I am not allowed to use these CSS pseudo-classes or CSS selectors:

  - `:nth-child`
  - `:nth-last-child`
  - `:nth-of-type`
  - `:nth-last-of-type`
  - `[data-target]`
  - nor any use of `+` or `~`
- Only one selector is allowed.

I have tried the following selector, but it still selects the third `div` (the one not marked with `data-target`):

```css
#task-5 section > div:not(:last-child):not(:is(:first-child:is(:last-child)))
```

Can you please help me. Thank you very much

Comment: Investigate attribute selectors - see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

Comment: Thank you A. Haworth. Sadly, I have already taken a look at the CSS attribute selectors, but since all the class attributes are the same, there is no way to distinguish them.

Comment: Have I misunderstood? I thought you needed to select just those two elements which have the data-target attribute?

Comment: Yes, I do. However, I am not allowed to use the data-target in my selector.

Comment: Ah, I don't see that specified in your question. Perhaps you could add it?

Comment: Oh, thank you. It seems that I forgot to add it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you can select the section that has another section as a descendant. Then you can select the divs that are not descendants of a section which is the descendant of a section.

```css
section:has(section) div:not(section section div) {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<h2>Task 5</h2>
<article id="task-5">
  <div class="marble">1</div>
  <div class="marble">2</div>
  <section>
    <div class="marble" data-target>3</div>
    <div class="marble" data-target>4</div>
    <section>
      <div class="marble">5</div>
      <div class="marble">6</div>
    </section>
  </section>
</article>
```

Note: currently :has is supported on Firefox only if a flag is set.

Comment: `:has()` is very, very, very new - As of September 2022 Firefox still doesn't support it and Chrome needs to be 105 or higher, but lots of people are still on v103 and 104.

Comment: @Dai, Firefox does support it behind the `layout.css.has-selector.enabled` flag; but otherwise: yes, it's probably still a little new (though Chrome is an evergreen browser, so most installations will update to 105 where possible).

Comment: @Dai yes, agreed.  I pointed out the FF problem. And of course we don't know the exact restrictions that are being placed on this question. However, as SO is for answers that might be useful in the future and as has is in the spec it seemed interesting anyway to include it.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest answer, so far as I can tell from your posted constraints, would be:

```
/* this uses the child combinator (`>`) to select
   the <div> elements which are the children of
   a <section> which is in turn a child of an
   <article>: */
article > section > div {
  background-color: lime;
}
```

```css
*,
 ::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

section {
  margin-inline-start: 10%;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

div {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin-inline-start: 10%;
  min-block-size: 2em;
}

article>section>div {
  background-color: lime;
}
```

```html
<h2>Task 5</h2>
<article id="task-5">
  <div class="marble"></div>
  <div class="marble"></div>
  <section>
    <div class="marble" data-target></div>
    <div class="marble" data-target></div>
    <section>
      <div class="marble"></div>
      <div class="marble"></div>
    </section>
  </section>
</article>
```

References:

- [Child combinator: `>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator).

Answer (score -2):

You can select the first child through:

```
element:first-child
```

and you can select last child:

```
element :last-child
```

and you have some method like:

- not()
- first-of-type
- last-of-type